# How to install cygwin/X through apt-cyg

Tags: windows, cygwin, x11

Anyone knows how to install cygwin/X through apt-cyg, no with setup.exe?

Answer (score 5):

```
wget rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg
install apt-cyg /bin
apt-cyg install xinit wget screen 
startxwin -- -nolock # FAT32 workaround
```